# Query regarding Facebook Connect on the website

Tags: facebook, authentication, registration, facebook-login

I have a website where I allow users to sign up using normal registration as well as login via facebook.

If the users signs up using normal registration then I want to provide him with an option of connect via facebook. I will give him this option to connect only if he is already logged in using normal login in this case.

So my problem is, how do I link the two accounts which may not have same email ids in this case? In other words I want to link these two accounts on my system.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

They don't need to have the same emails at all. The common practice is to have such DB schema.

1st table: `users`: `id, display_name, registration_date, ...`
2nd table: `auth_email`: `user_id, email, password, salt`
3rd table: `auth_facebook`: `user_id, facebook_id`

So you see - having Facebook user id you may find `user_id` on your site and authenticate the user.

In the similar way: having email + password from the login form - you can find `user_id` and authenticate the user

If you want to add another authentication schema - just add correspondent table with `user_id` foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Your answer provided me an idea how I could apply the same in my application.